# How to reserve() an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In C++, heap memory arrays, such as vectors, prevent array re-creation and copying through reserves.

ex)

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);
```

But I couldn't find anything that does this in javascript. I looked for a related reference, but couldn't find it. When the v8 engine compiles, if the array grows dynamically, does it reallocate?

If you have any information or knowledge related to this, please share!

Comment: Javascript `Array` is not a contiguous block of memory as in c++ and the language as a whole does not give programmer much freedom to manually manage memory. So reserve and reallocate terms from c++ do not apply to it at all. There is also `ArrayBuffer` which as indeed a contiguous block of memory but it's size is defined when it is created.

Comment: @user7860670 There’s a related proposal: [In-Place Resizable and Growable `ArrayBuffer`s](//github.com/tc39/proposal-resizablearraybuffer).

Comment: Does not answer your question, but maybe a good read on that topic: https://www.quora.com/Do-arrays-in-JavaScript-grow-dynamically

Comment: What about: [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) ?

Comment: @NirAlfasi The other comment got deleted, but _again_, this is about [`reserve`](//www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve), not `reverse`.

Comment: oh lol, my bad :)))

Comment: The proposal has also been [linked](/search?q=url%3Agithub.com%2Ftc39%2Fproposal-resizablearraybuffer) here: [Growable 8-bit byte buffer in JavaScript](/q/63388298/4642212).

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript does not use contiguous arrays. Internally, it has a hash map structure.

Comment: Yes, _`Array`_ objects may be implemented as a hash map in JS engines. That still doesn’t consider [TypedArrays](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typedarray-objects) and their implementation details and the [In-Place Resizable and Growable `ArrayBuffer`s proposal](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typedarray-objects) I mentioned in a previous comment. If your question is actually only about `Array` objects and not `TypedArray`s, you should clarify that, but decent JS introductions would’ve told you already that JS `Array`s aren’t really “arrays” in the traditional sense.